# Como posso alterar as labels de um gráfico no matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

**Meu código:**

```
dados.boxplot(column='NU_NOTA_LC', by = "TP_LINGUA",vert = 0)
plt.xlabel('Nota')
plt.ylabel('Linguas')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para alterar a legenda de 0 e 1 para respectivamente Inglês e Espanhol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `plt.yticks()` tanto para pegar quanto para setar as posições (*ticks*) e os rótulos (*labels*) do eixo Y (existe também a função análoga `plt.xticks()` para o eixo X).

Portanto, podemos chamar a função uma vez para pegar as posições, e uma segunda vez para setar os rótulos nas mesmas posições mas mudando o seu texto. Segue exemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Dados simulados
dados = pd.DataFrame({
    'NU_NOTA_LC': np.random.normal(loc=500, scale=100, size=1000),
    'TP_LINGUA': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000),
})
dados.boxplot(column='NU_NOTA_LC', by='TP_LINGUA', vert=0)
plt.xlabel('Nota')
plt.ylabel('Linguas')

# Código relevante para a pergunta
ticks, labels = plt.yticks()
plt.yticks(ticks, labels=['Inglês', 'Espanhol'])

plt.tight_layout()  # apenas pra facilitar a visualização
plt.show()
```

Figura gerada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, forte de mais.